# BaseAdapter onLongClick not fired

Tags: android, listview

I want to call `setOnLongClickListener` on the view returned from the `getView()` method, but it seems like it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    convertView.setLongClickable(true);
    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // this code does not execute
            return true;
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: But why are you implemented new `OnLongClickListener()` onto `convertView`? directly implement into `ListView`

Comment: @SimplePlan he is doing it `convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {`. convertView is probably the inflated layout

Comment: Put your whole code. Do you get any kind of error ? In  which view you are trying to add listener ?

Comment: @GrIsHu is a simple BaseAdapter implementation with a viewholder pattern it works fine if I add onClickListener to the view

Comment: Why the down vote? its a legitimate question.

Comment: @GrIsHu there I have added some code

Comment: Put your this line `viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();` in the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your long click listener to listview, not inside adapter. Like this:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I want to handle the event inside the adapter.

Comment: You can do what you want inside onItemLongClick. Can you tell me what you want to do ?

Comment: simply handle the event inside the adapter and not anywhere else, I could use the setOnItemLongClickListener on the listview, but I want to know why it doesn't work from the adapter.

Comment: then, can you please set your row views root element to android:clickable="true"

Comment: did you try ? @user1940676

Comment: You should put your row xml here.